# Counterpart to categorical crossentropy for not one-hot encoded labels

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm building a neural network with KERAS, where my labels are vectors, where exactly 6 values are 1, while all the other values (around 7000) are zero. I'm currently using `categorical_crossentropy` as my loss function but the documentation says:

> Note: when using the `categorical_crossentropy` loss, your targets should be in categorical format (e.g. if you have 10 classes, the target for each sample should be a 10-dimensional vector that is all-zeros except for a 1 at the index corresponding to the class of the sample).

So what would be the "right" error function if `categoreical_crossentropy` is only the right way for one-hot encoded labels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss, which accepts integer class indices instead of one-hot encoded ones.

Comment: But `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` will only take one number as a label and not a vector containing more than one 1 or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Noltibus Ah yes but wait, are you doing classification or regression?

Comment: My labels are vectors containing 6 ones, so it is a classification task? But I can't enumerate all versions of the labels because that would be 2^7000 right?

Comment: EDIT: The longer I look at it, I would say it is more of a regression problem.